# Workarounds for incorrect CPU thread and process times on Windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, time, cpu

Apparently there are many complaints about incorrect CPU usage under Windows 11, see for example here
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-22h2-all-monitoring-softwares-report/3e669b84-c0ac-427f-a29e-86debf2db43f?page=2
and here
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/yl3vxc/monitoring_programs_reports_wrong_cpu_load_on/?rdt=44755

Unfortunately, this also affects CPU process and CPU thread times. After updating to Windows 11, the measured CPU times are much smaller than the wall clock time. Here is how I measure CPU time:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "processthreadsapi.h"

// Returns CPU process time in milliseconds
static long long get_cpu_time()
{
    union FiletimeUnion
    {
        FILETIME  as_filetime;
        long long as_llong;
    };

    // Get process user and kernel times
    FILETIME create_time, exit_time;
    FiletimeUnion user_time, kernel_time;
    GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess(), &create_time, &exit_time, &kernel_time.as_filetime, &user_time.as_filetime);

    // Return sum of user and kernel times in milliseconds
    return (user_time.as_llong + kernel_time.as_llong) / 10000;
}

int main()
{
    // Measure start times
    const auto cpu_time_start = get_cpu_time();
    const auto wall_time_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Run application with a single thread
    // ...

    // Measure end times
    const auto cpu_time_end = get_cpu_time();
    const auto wall_time_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Get elapsed times in milliseconds
    const auto cpu_time_in_ms = static_cast<double>(cpu_time_end - cpu_time_start);
    const auto wall_time_in_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(wall_time_end - wall_time_start).count();

    std::cout << "CPU time:      " << cpu_time_in_ms << " ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wall time:     " << wall_time_in_ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For my application, I get

```
CPU time:      1468 ms
Wall time:     6900 ms
```

which is definetely wrong! (I'm working on an 12th Gen Intel Core Processor.)

My question is: Are there any known workarounds for incorrect CPU times on Windows 11?

What I have tried so far: I've found some workarounds in monitoring software that use CPU idle usage. (https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon/pull/167) I tried the same approach by measuring the process usage by the inverse of the idle "usage" of the process. From this and the wall clock time, I calculated the CPU time. This seemed to give good results when the CPU was not fully occupied, but failed when the CPU was heavily loaded.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `QueryPerformanceCounter` would give proper values (probably it's even used as an implementation). `GetProcessTimes` isn't really a wall clock, it's more like a uptime measure from process manager's perspective. `The time that each of the threads of the process has executed in kernel mode is determined, and then all of those times are summed together to obtain this value.` `Note that this value can exceed the amount of real time elapsed (between lpCreationTime and lpExitTime) if the process executes across multiple CPU cores.`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `QueryPerformanceCounter` ! However, I don't want to measure wall clock time but indeed CPU time for a process with multiple threads. The example is boiled down to a single thread and obviously fails even in this simple setting.

Comment: if would show wrong thing for short-living processes.There is something happening outside of your control beside your code. Now if your process would be long-running, the times become assymtotically close. QPC isn't really wall clock either, it's TSC, an instruction counter builtin  into CPU as defined by CPU performance. True wall clock (the battery-powered chip on MB) are slow and inprecise (consider +/- 30 ms at least), usually OS reads them on boot, sets when clock time is altered\corrected.